# Native thread never get processor time when AudioRecord running

Tags: multithreading, android-ndk, android-audiorecord

I'm making an application for some speech processing. For speech recording is used Android `AudioRecord` class. The `AudioRecord` instance is put in a service. A separate thread is used for calling `read()` method of  `AudioRecord` class (there are enough examples on SO). The read samples are forward to my native  code for further processing and they are put in some queue. In a native code one thread is doing the processing. The problem is this thread never gets a processor time. 
On finishing my app I call some function for cleaning my native resources. But it happens that whole process of cleaning isn't finished (I established it using calls). When I start the app again  my native processing is started (reading new samples isn't started yet).

Is it possible that reading thread is using processor just for itself? Could I set a higher priority for my native (processor) thread. Or it could be some other problem.

I've even tried using `AudioRecord.OnRecordPositionUpdateListener` and `onPeriodicNotification` but with no success.

Comment: have you tried to attach the native thread doing the processing to see if this let it get scheduled? How many native threads do you have working? How do you attach the one accessing the queue?

Comment: I have only this one native thread. I am not attaching the thread accessing the queue since I dont't have any info from java code..Why should I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It was an error in my ported library. One of processing blocks calls `sleep` method. This library was first used under windows and sleeping time was in milliseconds. After porting this time is in seconds. So my native thread was sleeping for 50 seconds instead 50 milliseconds.